# How to inject $templateCache into angular hybrid APP_INITIALIZER hook?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular5, hybrid

I'm new to Angular5 and TypeScript, so it's very possible it's a simple thing I'm overlooking.

I have an Angular hybrid app that uses ngUpgrade to run AngularJS and Angular5 side-by-side. I'm trying to inject `$templateCache` into the `OnAppInit` function so that I can load all the AngularJS HTML templates before the app completely initializes. I'm getting the error "**Cannot find name '$templateCacheService'**" as indicated below. Is my syntax wrong or is this not possible?

I "upgrade" `$templateCache` in `upgraded-providers.ts` like this:

```
import { InjectionToken, Directive, ElementRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

export const $templateCacheService = new InjectionToken<any>('$templateCacheService');
export const $templateCacheServiceProvider = {
  provide: $templateCacheService,
  useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('$templateCache'),
  deps: ['$injector']
};
```

Then in `app.module.ts`, I try to inject it into `OnAppInit`:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatCommonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { downgradeInjectable, UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import {
  $templateCacheServiceProvider,
  $templateCacheService
} from './upgraded-providers';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalVarsService } from './core/global-vars.service';
import { WinAuthInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/win-auth.interceptor';

declare var angular: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCommonModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: WinAuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: OnAppInit,
      multi: true,
      deps: [GlobalVarsService, HttpClient, $templateCacheService]
    },
    GlobalVarsService,
    $templateCacheServiceProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule, private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    angular.module('app').factory('globalVars', downgradeInjectable(GlobalVarsService));
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}

////// THIS NEXT LINE GETS error TS2304: Cannot find name '$templateCacheService' /////
export function OnAppInit(globalVars: GlobalVarsService, http: HttpClient, $templateCache: $templateCacheService) { 
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get(environment.apiBase + '/api/meta/data').subscribe(x => {
        globalVars.MetaData = x;
        globalVars.VersionNumber = globalVars.MetaData.versionNumber;
        globalVars.IsDebugBuild = globalVars.MetaData.isDebugBuild;
        globalVars.User = globalVars.MetaData.user;
        globalVars.ApiBase = environment.apiBase;
        globalVars.Templates.forEach(template => {
          $templateCache.put(template.Item1, template.Item2);
        });
        resolve();
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: At least $templateCacheService is not a valid type here, `$templateCache: $templateCacheService`. I guess the type is something like `ng.ITemplateCacheService`.

Comment: @estus, I use the same approach for other ng1 services that I need to inject into ng5 components and it works fine. Why would it be different here?

Comment: It's not about approach. It's about proper typing. $templateCacheService is not a correct type (not a type at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is TypeScript type error, it doesn't affect how the application works (as long as compilation errors are ignored).

`templateCacheService` is not a valid type here, because `$templateCacheService` is a variable (injection token), not a type or an interface.

Only Angular class constructors are annotated with types for DI. Since factory functions are annotated with `deps` property, types in function signature exist only to provide type safety. If it's not needed, types can be skipped:

```
export function OnAppInit(
  globalVars: GlobalVarsService, http: HttpClient,
  $templateCache
) { ... }
```

Otherwise proper types should be used. `$templateCache` is an object with `get`, `put`, etc methods. Appropriate types are provided with AngularJS `@types/angular` type definitions. It will be something like:

```
export function OnAppInit(
  globalVars: GlobalVarsService, http: HttpClient,
  $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService
) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I took off the type and now I'm getting the error "Trying to get the AngularJS injector before it being set." Do you notice anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: You likely need .bootstrap() in ngDoBootstrap, since it presumes that you will do all the work manually. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328290/3731501 . Your module also doesn't have entryComponents